# Hidden maven enforcer configuration?

Tags: apache, maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

Is there `non-pom.xml` configuration for the maven enforcer plugin?

I'm trying to compile an existing project, and it is failing with:

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4:enforce (enforce-versions) @ root-pom ---
[WARNING] Rule 4: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion failed with message:
Detected Maven Version: 3.3.9 is not in the allowed range [3.2.3,3.3).
```

I can't find enforcer configuration in *any* `pom.xml` file.
The Apache documentation simply states that configuration is in the pom.xml.

Comment: can you run `mvn help:effective-pom` and check if you are getting an enforcer configuration from a parent pom? Also `mvn help:active-profiles` to check which profile is active could help you out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks A. Di Matteo

displaying the effective pom (with `mvn help:effective-pom`) allowed me to see that the enforcer config was indeed coming from a parent pom.